# Cloudflare Api Status Endpoint

Tags: cloudflare

***Note**: This was also posted in [Cloudflare community forum](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/api-status/557939). In case they answer there, I will update this post.*

I've set up health checks in my applications, and the ones integrated with the Cloudflare API include a health check that verifies the response from https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/status for a success code.

However, for the past few months, this endpoint has been consistently returning a 400 (Bad Request) status code. It looks like the endpoint is gone. Here's the exact message from the health check:

`"Discover endpoint #0 is not responding with a code in the 200...299 range; the current status is BadRequest."`

This issue is causing my applications to remain in a degraded state continuously.

My question is, what has happened to this endpoint, and how can I determine the health status of the Cloudflare API?

For the record, I am using AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris from https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks and it looks something like

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddUrlGroup(new Uri("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/status"),
                 name: "Cloudflare API",
                 failureStatus: HealthStatus.Degraded)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a deprecated version of the Cloudflare APIs.

You can check the current version for **Health Checks** here:

https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/health-checks-health-check-details

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My interpretation of that endpoint is that it is an endpoint to check helthchecks of my website through the cloudflare healthcheck tool. What I need is to check that cloudflare api is up and running.
They used to have this status endpoint for that. Apparently they don't have it anymore. I will need to rely that the cloudflare API is always up and running. Which is fine as I keep history of failed requests and I can re-send them. It was mor for monitoring in real time.

Comment: BTW, I got a response from Cloudflare community. Apparently I should use https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/user-api-tokens-verify-token this endpoint to check the status. It is not specifically for the API Healthcheck, but it should work